# If-statement into the switch-method with boolean

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, boolean, syntax-error

**Problem**: How to write this if-codeblock into a switch case? I have only a problem with the boolean.

```
int Note = 0;

Console.WriteLine("What is your note?: ");
Note = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if ((Note < 1) || (Note > 6))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong!");
}
else 
{
   if (Note <= 4)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Passed");
   }
   else 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Failed");
   }

}
```

I tried to write this codeblock into a switch-method.

```
int Note = 0;
Console.WriteLine("What ist your note?: ");
Note = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (Note) 
{
   case Note < 1 || Note > 6: 
      Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong!");
         break;

   case Note <= 4:
      Console.WriteLine("Passed");
         break;
}
```

**Error Message**: I can't convert the string into int.

Comment: This is not where `switch` statements are for. You should keep using `if`.

Comment: What you feel wrong with `if..else`?

Comment: Why have you decided to use a switch statement instead?

Comment: Why do you want to replace those `if` statements at all? What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: This is correct, but my task is to write this if statement into the switch. I know, that the if-statement better is. Thanks.

Comment: Only for my exercise. This is a task from my studies.

Comment: Use range-based switching then instead of implementing a bunch of different cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#7+ supports range-based switching:

```
switch (Note)
{
    case int n when n< 1 || Note > 6:
        Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong!");
        break;
    case int n when n <= 4:
        Console.WriteLine("Passed");
        break;
}
```

Comment: This solution is way cleaner than manually handling every affected case and should be preffered.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that if you really need a switch

```
switch (Note)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("Passed");
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! ... Thanks for your help! ...  Little question.. Can you use a boolean in a switch statement?

Comment: Yes, `case true`, `case false`.

Comment: Note that this approach tend to become tedious if you have larger ranges.

Comment: @duuustin: Yes. Using range-based switching.

Answer (score 1):

This is not where `switch` statements are for. You should keep using `if`.

I will proof that very easily, using a `switch`, as you asked:

```
switch (Note) 
{
   case 1: 
   case 2: 
   case 3: 
   case 4: 
      Console.WriteLine("Passed");
         break;
   case 5: 
   case 6: 
      Console.WriteLine("Failed");
         break;
   default: 
      Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong!");
         break;
}
```

This is just way too verbatim. You don't want to write down every value. `if` is more appropriate.